# Link listBox with Database and show values in textBox if select index in listBox. C#

Tags: c#, mysql

That works on displaying the items from database in the listbox but i need that if i select a value in the listbox it displays information about that person back to the textboxes. Thats the thing that i can't get to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace program
{
    public partial class Form8 : Form
    {
        public Form8()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fill_listbox();
        }

        void fill_listbox()
        {
            string constring = "datasource=sql2.freesqldatabase.com;port=3306;username=sql217040;password=xxxxx";
            string Query = "select * from sql217040.fakedata ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string id1 = myReader.GetString("id");
                    string name1 = myReader.GetString("name");
                    string surname1 = myReader.GetString("surname");
                    listBox1.Items.Add(id1 + ' ' + name1 + ' ' + surname1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource=sql2.freesqldatabase.com;port=3306;username=sql217040;password=xxxxx";
            string Query = "select * from sql217040.fakedata where name='" + listBox1.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    string sname = myReader.GetString("name");
                    string ssurname = myReader.GetString("surname");
                    string sphone = myReader.GetString("phone");
                    textBox1.Text = sname;
                    textBox2.Text = ssurname;
                    //telephone.Text = sphone;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the right tool for the job. Instead of listbox you should use listview/datagridview. This will save you round trips to database as well/

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: values in textBoxes not appears when I select indexes in listBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ideally i would change your listbox to datagridview and change your method like this

```
void fill_listbox()
    {
       try
        {
        string constring = "datasource=sql2.freesqldatabase.com;port=3306;username=sql217040;password=xxxxx";
        string Query = "select * from sql217040.fakedata ;";
        using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conDataBase))
            {
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);          
                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView1.DataSource = t; // <-- datagridview1 is the gridview i have added
         }
       }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
       }
    }
```

and read the values like this from cell double click event of gridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["columnname"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use DataSet instead of DataReader.

Just add all items into the listbox and get the selected item from DataSet by the listbox selectedItemIndex. This will save the the extra query when listbox selected index changed.